# Export ggplot to eps and keep text as text element

Tags: r, ggplot2, eps

I would like to export a graph from `ggplot` to .eps format so I can edit it in illustrator software (I use Affinity Designer). My problem is that when I open the eps file, text is considered as vector shapes and *not* text. It would be easier and faster if text elements are exported directly as text and this seems possible from other posts I've read.

I plot my graph with the following code - there isn't anything really special happening here:

```
mosai %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Elements_mosai, y = Area_km2, fill = Période)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1, position = "dodge") + 
  scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("Avant restauration","Pendant restauration", "Après restauration"), 
values = c("#E7298A", "#A6761D", "#66A61E")) +
      labs(x = "Eléments de la mosaïque paysagère", y = "Superficie (km2)") + 
      facet_wrap(~ Rivière + Type) + 
      theme_bw()
```

I am using `theme_bw` from `ggplot` which uses the font "TT Arial", here is more informations on that:

```
List of 11
 $ family       : chr ""
 $ face         : chr "plain"
 $ colour       : chr "black"
 $ size         : num 11
 $ hjust        : num 0.5
 $ vjust        : num 0.5
 $ angle        : num 0
 $ lineheight   : num 0.9
 $ margin       : 'margin' num [1:4] 0points 0points 0points 0points
  ..- attr(*, "unit")= int 8
 $ debug        : logi FALSE
 $ inherit.blank: logi TRUE
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "element_text" "element"

> windowsFonts()
$serif
[1] "TT Times New Roman"

$sans
[1] "TT Arial"

$mono
[1] "TT Courier New"
```

I then save my plot with this command:

```
ggsave("test.eps", device = "eps", plot = last_plot(), path = DIR_OUT, width = 40, 
height = 20, units = "cm", dpi = 500)
```

Maybe there is a parameter to make `ggsave` save text as text?

**EDIT 1**

In response to Andy Baxter's comment, here is a screenshot of my eps file opened in a text viewer.
[image: Beginning of the file]

[image: End of the file]

Comment: There's a good chance that it *is* saving the text but that the editor isn't importing text? If you open the eps file in a text editor and search for "Avant restauration" for example does it appear somewhere there as a text label? You could also try importing in another editor such as Inkscape and see if it has editable text.

Comment: I've tried to open it in another editor (Gimp), it showed things as pixels, not text. I couldn't open it in InkScape, I got an error. 

I opened it in a text editor and I have updated my post with some screenshots of this. It seems the eps has Helvetica font, not TT Arial inside it. But we can see at the bottom of the file some of the text is actually added to the eps, maybe it just can't find the font?

Comment: It does appear that Affinity [doesn't allow editable text in eps files](https://forum.affinity.serif.com/index.php?/topic/58958-editing-text-in-an-eps-file/). You could try saving as svg and editing in gimp/inkscape for text elements?

Comment: Thank you, that's great! I didn't think that the problem would be Affinity! I'm saving in svg and it works now.